# Set background color of a shape programmatically

Tags: android

I need to change background color of a shape programmatically, but I don't know how. Here what I have done so far:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/linearlayout_mediagalleryicon"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:background="@drawable/circle_visual_feedback_selector"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:padding="10dp"
   android:clickable="true">
<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/imageview_mediagalleryicon"
   android:layout_width="35dp"
   android:layout_height="35dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

circle_visual_feedback_selector.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/circle_visual_feedback" />
</selector>
```

circle_visual_feedback.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#40808080"/>
    <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" android:left="10dp"></padding>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you are trying to do, but this may help you.

```
((GradientDrawable)yourView.getBackground()).setColor(yourColor);
```

Comment: I have tried this, it set's the background of all the LinearLayout, not just the circle

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
findViewById(R.id.linearlayout_mediagalleryicon)
     .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circle_visual_feedback);
```

This changes the background of your **LinearLayout** to **circle_visual_feedback**.

Answer (score 0):

`view.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);`

SRC_IN means it should only apply the color to your circle

Comment: I get NullPointerException when I use this line of code with my ImageView object. I applied it to the linearlayout but nothing changed.

Comment: Thats because your ImageView doesn't have a background applied to it. May I ask why you don't just correct the colour in xml instead of programatically? Is it dynamic?

Comment: Yes it is dynamic

Comment: I just recreated your code exactly and it works for me, can you edit your question to include where and how you are setting the colorfilter so I can help you further?